# Hover state on image using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, hover, tailwind-css

I need help on the hover state. I'm using Tailwind, and I need to make an image with a transparent background(bg-blue-300) on top of it when I hover. Below is my code; I tried several changes. Can anyone help me?

```
<a href="#" class="hover:bg-blue-600">
    <img class="w-full rounded-md" src="/images/image-sample.jpg"> 
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="bg-blue-300 inline-block">
    <img class="w-full rounded-md hover:opacity-[0]" src="/images/image-sample.jpg">
</a>
```

Your image is covering the background
Of  tag and so the background;
add opacity to your image on hover and also add inline-block to anchor tag as links are inline by default so they don't have heights therefor no background-color

Comment: This works really. Thank you so much @Aakash, I learn something on the code snippet too.